# Form Resize control issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, mdi, resize

I made a simple application in which an MDI parent loads a child form at a click of a menu item..(I am going to implement this in a much bigger and more useful application)...It contains initially a MenuStrip and on a click of the MenuStrip item a new form will open (typical MDI parent form style) This form is border less and I would like it to fit and fill the remaining space under the the MDI parents MenuStrip.

I need to know the properties to use in order to achieve this and at the same time (for the child form) to fit into the MDI parent form's free space at any resolution at which the display is.

So far I tried this but I got this error: Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

```
Private Sub frmGenPay_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.StartPosition(10, 10)
    Call FitToScreenCompanyDetails()
End Sub
```

In the module:

```
 Public Sub FitToScreen()
    frmMDImainform.Size = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Size
End Sub
```

The second code above is for the MDI parent form if someone could give me some suggestions on this too it would be really kick-start things.

Thanks to everyone for any piece of advice. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Me.StartPosition(10, 10)
```

That just isn't valid code.  StartPosition is a property, you are treating it as though it is a method.  Nor does it take a location.  My best guess for the intended code:

```
    Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Me.Location = New Point(10, 10)
```

You'll run into more trouble implementing your intended design.  There should be only one MDI main window.  MDI child windows cannot be borderless.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about startpositions, sizes and bounds, why can't you just (in the child form) set:

`Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`
`Me.MdiParent = myMDIParent`